# How to build an ensemble for different set of features?

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-learning

I have a dataset in which part of the features have more data than the other part, and for avoiding to build a full data set with a small amount of data, I'd like to build two models, each one receiving each part of the dataset as an input, and after the training step, somehow I'd like to combine them.

So, my question is: How can I create an ensemble for the models of this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify the setup?  Is it that some features are missing for a specific population?  Are the feature sets for your suggested two models disjoint?  Are the populations for your suggested two models disjoint?

Comment: Yes for all. The first population does not have the features of the second population. And both population are going to be the input of different models (not necessarily different algorithms). Each model will be trained either in the first or in the second population.